# Send a audio recorded file from frontend to django view

Tags: javascript, django, audio, django-views

Hi im trying to send a recorded audio to django backend. I used js to record the audio, How can i send it to django backend view (Maybe using POST method).

Frontend:
`

```
<button type="button" id="record">Record</button>
<button type="button" id="stopRecord" disabled>Stop</button>
        </p>
        <p>
<audio id=recordedAudio></audio>        

<script> 
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
    .then(stream => {handlerFunction(stream)})

    function handlerFunction(stream) {
      rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if (rec.state == "inactive"){
          let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/mp3'});

          recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          recordedAudio.controls=true;
          recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
          sendData(blob)
          }
        }
      }
    
    function sendData(data) {}
      record.onclick = e => {
        record.disabled = true;
        record.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
        stopRecord.disabled=false;
        audioChunks = [];
        rec.start();
        }
      stopRecord.onclick = e => {
        record.disabled = false;
        stop.disabled=true;
        record.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        rec.stop();
        }
  </script>
```

`

How can I send this recorded audio to django view? Thank you.

I want to get this recorded audio file into my django views.py.